# my table is not installing in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, php-5.4, install-script

In my Module have a table script inside the `InstallSchema` class. When I ran the below commands, it's not installing.

**Commands**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
```

But I have created the same code as another new module, and I have executed the above commands it's installed.

Is there any table to clear the module version in Magento 1 like (`core_resource`)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In **Magento 2** version information is stored on `setup_module` table. So you can remove your module and re run the commands it will work.

Comment: Timely help. +1, is it the standard procedure to install the script? Or a shortcut in case of not installing after upgrade?

Comment: @Butterfly if you specify versions magento will install automatically when run the upgrade command other wise need to remove module from setup_module table and run the upgrade command.

Answer (score 2):

Some time there may an entry for you module in

```
 app/etc/config.php
```

with value 0. And if you run the command

```
 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

then it will not upgrade your plugin. Change the vaue to 1 and run the command again.

Comment: This helped me :) Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Please check entry in `setup_module` table.and also check InstallSchema class name and namespace according to your module.delete entry from `setup_module` and run command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

If your module is created successful but not stored in setup_module table, check out you not missing the **setup_version** in your xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```